# responsive gatsby image in flexbox container

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I am struggling to get gatsby-image working with flexbox in a responsive way:

I would like all my images the same size and height and they should be responsive for mobile and desktop.

Is this the use case for gatsby image?

The only way I could get it to show was to add a fixed `minWidth`:

```
<div className={styles.header}>
  <GatsbyImage className={styles.image} fluid={image.fluid} style={{ minWidth: '100px' }} />
```

I tried to update the `graphQl` query to

```
          fluid(maxWidth: 100) {
            ...GatsbyContentfulFluid
          }
```

There is no minWidth only maxWidth.

I'm clearly totally missing how to use this.

How can I use gatsby-image in a flexbox container and I want all images to be the same size and height.

Comment: Not sure it helps your exact issue, But you can style both the image and the container that gatsby-image generates with their respective style props. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542305/how-to-display-images-without-cropping-using-gatsby-image/57553013#57553013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Gatsby Image with Contentful, but usually for Gatsby Image I wrap each image component in a div and control the size that way.

```
import Img from "gatsby-image"

...

<div className="img-wrap">
    <Img fluid={image.childImageSharp.fluid} style={{width: "100%"}} />
</div>
```

//CSS

```
.img-wrap {
    width: 15vw;
}
```

The 'childImageSharp' bit in my GraphQL query is just in line with the standard Gatsby documentation; it may not be relevant for your case using Contentful.

Comment: thank you, it feels like it is defeating the purpose if I have to wrap it in a div and give it my own dimensions.  I thought I could just write a graphql query.

Comment: @dagda1 You don't have to do that; it's just a brute-force way of doing it. I've seen some pretty inconsistent behavior with Gatsby Image, so that's why I do it.

Comment: the image does not show without setting a width on the container